# How to use form view helper into custom view helper in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, view-helpers

I am creating custom view helper. and i want to know how can i use formElement "Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement" in my own view helper. Here is my code.

```
use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
use Zend\Form\FieldsetInterface;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;

class JudgeCareerViewHelper extends AbstractHelper {
    private $output;
    public function __invoke($formCollection) {
    foreach ($formCollection as $elementOrFieldset) {
        if ($elementOrFieldset instanceof FieldsetInterface) {
            $obj = new FormElement();
            $this->output .= $obj($elementOrFieldset->get('startServiceDate'));
        } elseif ($elementOrFieldset instanceof ElementInterface) {
            //set element markup
            echo 'element';
        }
    };
    echo $this->output;

    die();
 }
}
```

When i `echo` the output return from `FormElement` is empty. So i opened the zend "Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement"  library to find out where is the problem. So i found that, below code return empty. I dont know what is the purpose of  `$renderer = $this->getView();` and how to get view.

```
$renderer = $this->getView();
        if (!method_exists($renderer, 'plugin')) {
            // Bail early if renderer is not pluggable
            return '';
        }
```

**Purpose of creating custom view helper to generate my own markup (HTML) instead of zend buitin html.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I found that, code `$renderer = $this->getView()` return empty.

You will need to ensure that the view helper is not directly instantiated using `new` but is called via the `Zend\View\HelperPluginManager`.

I *suspect* that the issue is because it is not correctly registered with the service manager as an `invokable` class.

```
// Module.php
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'JudgeCareer'
                => 'FooModule\Form\View\Helper\JudgeCareerViewHelper',  
        ),
    );
 }
```

This is to ensure that the [`Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer` is injected as the view](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/HelperPluginManager.php#L135).

Once the `JudgeCareerViewHelper` has the 'view' injected it would then be able to call other view plugins and have them loaded correctly, again via the `HelperPluginManager`.

The line:

```
$obj = new FormElement();
```

Should then be

```
$object = $this->getView()->plugin('form_element');
```

Comment: Thanks, You Solved my Problem. I spent 2 days to figure out where is the problem! How you know that i should not directly instantiate $obj = new FormElement(); but rather than $object = $this->getView()->plugin('form_element'); ?

Answer (score 0):

You may call any view helper from within your custom view helper by using

```
$this->getView()->anyRegisteredViewHelper();
```

So in your case to call the ZF2 built in form rendering view helpers you would use:

```
$this->getView()->formElement($element);
```

Whereby $element is your Form Element object (Select/Textarea/Checkbox etc)

You can of course also call explicit helpers for specific elements:

```
$this->getView()->formTextarea($textareaElement);
```